# how to get first day of next month with year (mm/dd/yyyy) in SSIS expression builder?

Tags: ssis

i need to build an expression such that the first day of next month is fetched. for eg. if i run the job in jan on any day of this year, the expression should fetch the date 02/01/2023. but when its the end of the year (in the month of december) for eg, if i am running the job on 12/29/2022, the expression should fetch 01/01/2023 (here the year is added).

```
RIGHT( "0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) MONTH(DATEADD("MM", 1, GETDATE())), 2) +"/01"+"/"+((DT_WSTR, 4) year(getdate()))
```

Issue – when the extract is run on  dec 2022, it should fetch the job date as 1/1/2023, instead, the output was 01/01/2022. The year variable needs to be fixed such that every year, when the job is run in the month of december, it should fetch the following year. Can someone please help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how the SSIS expression returned Feb 1 2022, if it was run any time in December. I'd believe that it returned Jan 1, 2022.

The approach you're taking is to use the named date part functions to extract a month and year value from `GETDATE()` and a hard coded day of the first.

You modify the month to add 1 to it and get next month and that's correct<sup>*</sup>, but incomplete.

But you're never testing whether you need to add one to the year value.
And you only need to do that if the current month is 12.

Personally, I don't like lots of logic in my Expressions. I would implement this as the following

Create a new SSIS variable called `CurrentDate` of type DateTime and set the value to `2022-12-31`. While testing, we're going to modify this value but once we're satisfied with what we've done, we'll use an Expression of GETDATE() or my preference of tying it in to `@[System::StartTime]`

Create an new SSIS Variable called `NextMonth` of type DateTime. In the Expression, use the following

```
DATEADD("month", 1, @[User::CurrentDate])
```

Verify it shows 2023-01-31. Change CurrentDate to 2023-01-31 and confirm it shows 2023-02-28, etc. Check any other boundary conditions you might be worried about.

Finally, we're ready to manipulate the original expression. At this point, we know what "next month" is and it handles year roll over so all this expression is going to do is build a string that has a hard coded day of 1, or 01 in this case.

I'll assume you have an SSIS Variable named `StartOfNextMonth` also DateTime. We'll use the same logic for padding out month and day with a zero. Since the data type is DateTime, I'm going to reorder the string to be YYYY-MM-DD as I always have to click the user's profile and see their country of origin as I don't know if 01/02/2023 is January 2, 2023 or February 1, 2023.

```
(DT_DATE)((DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(@[User::NextMonth]) + "-" + RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(@[User::NextMonth]), 2)+ "-01")
```

Breaking that down into pieces, the psuedo logic is "Cast everything to DT_DATE data type.

Where everything is

- `((DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(@[User::NextMonth]` Build a 4 character string of the year value from our variable next month
- `+ "-"` Append an dash to the year string
- `RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(@[User::NextMonth]), 2)` Cast the Month value of our variable for next month to string. Pre-pend a zero to that string and the slice off the last 2 characters. This is easier logic than testing whether the month number is 1 to 9 and only prepending a zero in those cases.
- `+ "-01"` Append a dash and hard coded 01 to the month string

Comment: thanks! you're right. My expression returned Jan 1, 2022. I should probably edit my question.

Comment: No problem and welcome to SO. If this answer solves the problem, there should be a check mark next it you can click to mark the question as resolved

Comment: Thankkyou, I'm glad to be here